# Show Primary Category first when I display post categories

Tags: functions, categories, order, sort

I created some custom taxonomies in Wordpress and when I want to show the categories for a custom post type on the frontend, they're listed in alphabetical order.

Is there a code for functions.php that can help me list the **Primary Category first**, then the other categories?

[image]

In the example above, categories show up as "Americas, Europe, Global", but I would like them sorted as "**Global**, Americas, Europe". The first one should be the primary category, then the others listed in alphabetical order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Yoast SEO plugin - I haven't tested this, but I think you can do something like this:
(Source https://pretagteam.com/question/get-primary-category-if-more-than-one-is-selected)

```
/*
Checks for a yoast primary category, if it exists move the category to the first position in the $categories array.
*/
function yoast_primary_cat_as_first_cat($categories) {

   // Check if yoast exists and get the primary category
   if ($categories && class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')) {

      // Show the post's 'Primary' category, if this Yoast feature is available, & one is set
      $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term('category', get_the_id());
      $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
      $term = get_term($wpseo_primary_term);

      // If no error is returned, get primary yoast term 
      $primary_cat_term_id = (!is_wp_error($term)) ? $term->term_id : null;

      // Loop all categories
      if ($primary_cat_term_id !== null) {
         foreach($categories as $i => $category) {

            /* Move the primary category to the top of the array
    and leave the rest of the categories in the order they were in */

            if ($category->term_id === $primary_cat_term_id) {

               $out = array_splice($categories, $i, 1);
               array_splice($categories, 0, 0, $out);

               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   return $categories;
}
add_filter('get_the_categories', 'yoast_primary_cat_as_first_cat');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'm trying to see how I can edit it to work for custom taxonomies. Because I want to reorder categories of a custom post type.

Comment: I think you can do that by changing
new WPSEO_Primary_Term('category', get_the_id());  to new WPSEO_Primary_Term('the-name-of-your-custom-taxonomy', get_the_id());

Comment: It's not working for me, unfortunately. I think maybe I should go with a plugin for custom order, although I preferred it like this.

Comment: @Mr.Fontastic did you finally manage to solve this issue? I have the same requirement and been looking all around for solutions.